# gmaps marker size based on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, dtype

I am trying to create a bubble map in gmaps, with size of bubble based on values in a column in a pandas dataframe. I am getting the error 
*'TraitError: The 'scale' trait of a Symbol instance must be an int, but a value of 2335  was specified.'*

My dataset is this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

I am naming the dataframe 'cgr' and then my code is this:

```
data_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
cgr[['Lat','Long']], fill_color='green', stroke_color='green', scale=cgr['5/1/20']
)

fig = gmaps.figure()

fig.add_layer(data_layer)

fig
```

I don't understand why gmaps is not recognising the numpy.int64 numbers as ints, and I cannot convert them to native python ints. Any ideas?

Here is the full Traceback

```
TraitError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-202e1cec5d37> in <module>
      1 data_layer = gmaps.symbol_layer(
----> 2 cgr[['Lat','Long']], fill_color='green', stroke_color='green', scale=cgr['5/1/20']
      3 )
      4 fig = gmaps.figure()
      5 fig.add_layer(data_layer)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gmaps\marker.py in symbol_layer(locations, hover_text, fill_color, fill_opacity, stroke_color, stroke_opacity, scale, info_box_content, display_info_box)
    479         fill_opacity, stroke_color, stroke_opacity, scale,
    480         info_box_content, display_info_box)
--> 481     symbols = [Symbol(**option) for option in options]
    482     return Markers(markers=symbols)
    483 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gmaps\marker.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    479         fill_opacity, stroke_color, stroke_opacity, scale,
    480         info_box_content, display_info_box)
--> 481     symbols = [Symbol(**option) for option in options]
    482     return Markers(markers=symbols)
    483 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gmaps\marker.py in __init__(self, location, **kwargs)
    162         kwargs = _resolve_info_box_kwargs(**kwargs)
    163         kwargs['location'] = location
--> 164         super(Symbol, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    165 
    166 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\widget.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    410         """Public constructor"""
    411         self._model_id = kwargs.pop('model_id', None)
--> 412         super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    413 
    414         Widget._call_widget_constructed(self)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    995             for key, value in kwargs.items():
    996                 if self.has_trait(key):
--> 997                     setattr(self, key, value)
    998                 else:
    999                     # passthrough args that don't set traits to super

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in __set__(self, obj, value)
    583             raise TraitError('The "%s" trait is read-only.' % self.name)
    584         else:
--> 585             self.set(obj, value)
    586 
    587     def _validate(self, obj, value):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in set(self, obj, value)
    557 
    558     def set(self, obj, value):
--> 559         new_value = self._validate(obj, value)
    560         try:
    561             old_value = obj._trait_values[self.name]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in _validate(self, obj, value)
    589             return value
    590         if hasattr(self, 'validate'):
--> 591             value = self.validate(obj, value)
    592         if obj._cross_validation_lock is False:
    593             value = self._cross_validate(obj, value)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in validate(self, obj, value)
   1868     def validate(self, obj, value):
   1869         if not isinstance(value, int):
-> 1870             self.error(obj, value)
   1871         return _validate_bounds(self, obj, value)
   1872 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py in error(self, obj, value)
    623             e = "The '%s' trait must be %s, but a value of %r was specified." \
    624                 % (self.name, self.info(), repr_type(value))
--> 625         raise TraitError(e)
    626 
    627     def get_metadata(self, key, default=None):

TraitError: The 'scale' trait of a Symbol instance must be an int, but a value of 2335 <class 'numpy.int64'> was specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for gmaps it uses the library *[traitlets](https://traitlets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)* for ensuring valid type usage.

https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/blob/4f75c8301de00fd831449fe685bd209b5f5ee3e3/gmaps/marker.py#L137

The specific section:

```
...
from traitlets import Unicode, Int, List, observe, HasTraits, Bool
...
scale = Int(
    default_value=4, allow_none=True, min=1
).tag(sync=True)
```

As far as I am aware, traitlets doesn't provide support for Numpy types, so you will need to convert this back to a Python Integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to convert to a Python Integer, but gmaps is still recognizing the number as a numpy.int64. Maybe my syntax is wrong.